# Find which phrases have been used multiple times in a string

Tags: c#, algorithm, text

It's easy to count occurrences of words in a file by using a Dictionary to identify which words are used the most frequently, but given a text file, how can I find commonly used phrases where a "phrase" is a set of two **or more** consecutive words?

For example, here is some sample text:

> Except oral wills, every will shall be in writing, but may be
>   handwritten or typewritten. The will shall contain the **testator's signature**
>   or by some other person in the testator's **conscious presence**
>   and at the testator's express direction . The will shall be attested
>   and subscribed in the **conscious presence** of the testator, by two or
>   more competent witnesses, who saw the testator subscribe, or heard the
>   testator acknowledge the **testator's signature**.
>
> For purposes of this section, **conscious presence** means within the
>   range of any of the testator's senses, excluding the sense of sight or
>   sound that is sensed by telephonic, electronic, or other distant
>   communication.

How can I identify that the phrases "conscious presence" (3 times) and "testator's signature" (2 times) as having appeared more than once (apart from brute force searching for every set of two or three words)?

I'll be writing this in c#, so c# code would be great, but I can't even identify a good algorithm so I'll settle for any code at all or even pseudo code for how to solve this.

Comment: Is "the testator's" a phrase? Because it shows up more than any other word combination.

Comment: YES! exactly "the testator's" is a phrase and I didn't even see that. It's hard to know what to look for which is why I need some algorithm for finding these consecutive, identical words.

Comment: What defines a "phrase"? Any two words? A user-defined list? If you are not giving a list of items to look for, you HAVE to brute-force your way through.

Comment: So anything constitutes a phrase as long as it's repeated?

Comment: Yes, any run of identical, consecutive words in a "phrase". There is no user-defined list, or the problem would be trivial. I suspect there's a better solution that brute force. Let's say the string is a full book of text. Brute force won't do so there needs to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Look into n-grams: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram. A lot of research has been done on this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thought I'd have a quick go at this - not sure if this isn't the brute force method you were trying to avoid - but :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string txt = @"Except oral wills, every will shall be in writing, 
but may be handwritten or typewritten. The will shall contain the testator's 
signature or by some other person in the testator's conscious presence and at the
testator's express direction . The will shall be attested and subscribed in the
conscious presence of the testator, by two or more competent witnesses, who saw the
testator subscribe, or heard the testator acknowledge the testator's signature.

For purposes of this section, conscious presence means within the range of any of the
testator's senses, excluding the sense of sight or sound that is sensed by telephonic,
electronic, or other distant communication.";

    //split string using common seperators - could add more or use regex.
    string[] words = txt.Split(',', '.', ';', ' ', '\n', '\r');

    //trim each tring and get rid of any empty ones
    words = words.Select(t=>t.Trim()).Where(t=>t.Trim()!=string.Empty).ToArray();

    const int MaxPhraseLength = 20;

    Dictionary<string, int> Counts = new Dictionary<string,int>();

    for (int phraseLen = MaxPhraseLength; phraseLen >= 2; phraseLen--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            //get the phrase to match based on phraselen
            string[] phrase = GetPhrase(words, i, phraseLen);
            string sphrase = string.Join(" ", phrase);

            Console.WriteLine("Phrase : {0}", sphrase);

            int index = FindPhraseIndex(words, i+phrase.Length, phrase);

            if (index > -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Phrase : {0} found at {1}", sphrase, index);

                if(!Counts.ContainsKey(sphrase))
                    Counts.Add(sphrase, 1);

                Counts[sphrase]++;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var foo in Counts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - {1}", foo.Key, foo.Value);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static string[] GetPhrase(string[] words, int startpos, int len)
{
    return words.Skip(startpos).Take(len).ToArray();
}

static int  FindPhraseIndex(string[] words, int startIndex, string[] matchWords)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        int j;

        for(j=0; j<matchWords.Length && (i+j)<words.Length; j++)
            if(matchWords[j]!=words[i+j])
                break;

        if (j == matchWords.Length)
            return startIndex;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You've done it - works perfectly. I think if I first look for single words occurring more than once and then look for phrases stemming from them and maybe phrases stemming from those phrases, I can minimize the work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped - love these little problems.  I'm sure you could make it much more efficient - this is just as it came out of my head.

Comment: There are many algorithms for [collocation extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_extraction) that might be more efficient than this one.

Answer (score 5):

Try this out. It's in no way fool-proof, but should get the job done for now.

Yes, this only matches 2-word combos, does not strip punctuation, and is brute-force. No, the `ToList` is not necessary.

```
string text = "that big long text block";

var splitBySpace = text.Split(' ');

var doubleWords = splitBySpace
    .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
    .Where(x => x.Index != splitBySpace.Length - 1)
    .Select(x => x.Value + " " + splitBySpace.ElementAt(x.Index + 1)).ToList();

var duplicates = doubleWords
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList();
```

I got the following results:

[image]

---

Here is my attempt at getting more than 2 word combos. Again, same warning as previous.

```
List<string> multiWords = new List<string>();

//i is the number of words to combine
//in this case, 2-6 words
for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
{
    multiWords.AddRange(splitBySpace
        .Select((x, index) => new { Value = x, Index = index })
        .Where(x => x.Index != splitBySpace.Length - i + 1)
        .Select(x => CombineItems(splitBySpace, x.Index, x.Index + i - 1)));
}

var duplicates = multiWords
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).ToList();

private string CombineItems(IEnumerable<string> source, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    return string.Join(" ", source.Where((x, i) => i >= startIndex && i <= endIndex).ToArray());
}
```

The results this time:
[image]

Now I just want to say there is a high chance of a off-by-one error with my code. I did not fully test it, so make sure you test it before you use it.

Comment: This is really great - thanks! But how to extend this to 3, 4 or 5 words? There very quickly becomes too many combinations to consider. I guess I could trim it to words that occur more than once and then even use this to find phrases of 2 words and then look for an additional word beyond the 2. Anyway, thanks - this is a great help!

Comment: @powlette, no problem. I updated my answer to try doing more than 2 words. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing it, I would probably be starting with the brute force approach, but it sounds like you want to avoid that.  A two-phase approach could do a count of each word, take the top few results (only start with the top few words that appear the most times), then search for and count only phrases that include these popular words.  Then you won't spend your time searching over *all* phrases.

I have this feeling that CS folks will correct me saying that this would actually take more time than a straight up brute force.  And maybe some linguists will pitch in with some methods for detecting phrases or something.

Good luck!

Comment: Instead of counting word frequency, maybe start with brute-forcing two-word "phrases". Then for that list, check the words on either side for equality. The most frequent word(s) may not even be present in "multiple" phrases, but the most frequent two-word phrases definitely will be.