# Find phrases used multiple times in string

Tags: c#

**UPDATE**

Sorry, i have little English.

I want to count phrase(s) in string.

My string is below;

> **Lorem ipsum** dolor **sit amet**, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla
>   venenatis, **lorem ipsum** augue vel pellentesque **sit amet**, **lorem ipsum** dolor egestas lacus,
>   et ipsum dolor nulla.

I want at below;

> - 3x *Lorem ipsum*
> - 2x *sit amet*

I tried function in this link
[Find which phrases have been used multiple times in a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641986/find-which-phrases-have-been-used-multiple-times-in-a-string)

**But my results below;**

- repeated = 10080x (It's counting spaces?)
- repeated  = 99x photoshop
- repeated  = 52x dersleri
- repeated  = 44x photoshop dersleri
- repeated  = 36x photoshop ile

**But i want to below;**

- repeated  = 44x photoshop dersleri
- repeated  = 36x photoshop ile
- repeated = and others...

I used this function;

```
var splitBySpace = text2.Split(' ');

var doubleWords = splitBySpace
        .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
        .Where(x => x.Index != splitBySpace.Length - 1)
        .Select(x => x.Value + " " + splitBySpace.ElementAt(x.Index + 1));

var duplicates = doubleWords
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(w => w.Count);

foreach (var word in duplicates)
    ensikkelimeler.Add(string.Format("{0}x {1}", word.Count, word.Key));
```

Comment: It repeats "photoshop" although not even being present in the original string???

Comment: Photoshop word used 99 times in my string. But i don't want one words. I need two words. Not "photoshop", it will be "photoshop dersleri".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked your code (it seems to be from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18642391/197913)) a bit (I described the changes in comments):

```
// all separators from sample text, add additional if necessary
var splitBySpace = text2.Split(new[] {' ', '.', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var doubleWords = splitBySpace
    // make the search case insensitive
    .Select((x, i) => new {Value = x.ToLowerInvariant(), Index = i})
    .Where(x => x.Index != splitBySpace.Length - 1)
    .Select(x => x.Value + " " + splitBySpace.ElementAt(x.Index + 1));

var ensikkelimeler = doubleWords
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => new {x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
    .OrderByDescending(w => w.Count)
    // do the formatting inside the link expression
    .Select(word => string.Format("{0}x {1}", word.Count, word.Key))
    .ToList();
```

These are the results for your sample text:

```
3x lorem ipsum 
3x ipsum dolor 
2x sit amet
```

I also tried out the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18642391/197913) from the question you linked to. After I added a call to `ToLowerInvariant()` it returned the same results for two-word phrases, but also included a three-word phrase:

```
2x lorem ipsum dolor 
3x lorem ipsum 
3x ipsum dolor 
2x sit amet
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized that this was downvoted by me by accident and now I can't reverse that downvote because it has been a while. Can you please edit the answer so it allows me to change my vote to an upvote rather than a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
             Nulla venenatis, lorem ipsum augue vel pellentesque sit amet, 
             lorem ipsum dolor egestas lacus, et ipsum dolor nulla.";

var phrases = new string[] { "sit amet", "lorem ipsum" };

var q = phrases.Select(p => new { phrase = p, Count =  CountPhraseInText(text, p) })
               .OrderBy(x => x.Count);
```

CountPhraseInText Function:

```
int CountPhraseInText(string input, string phrase)
{
     return new Regex(phrase, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(input).Count;
}
```